# How to Setup Stepped Country-wise launches for the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

So I have a weird situation for the iOS app store.

- We have an app that is currently live in India and Canada. We did this to get some real-world testing done before we launch everywhere (testflight beta with 1000 testers was not available when we started)
- Now we are planning prerelease marketing for US and RoW launch. We need to issue promo codes to reviewers for writing reviews.

Now the problem: Since our app pricing page has only India and Canada selected, the promo codes issued don't work for rest of the countries. Now I can select all the countries, but that would make it live everywhere *right now* - I don't have an option to "stage" it for rest of the countries but keep it live for India and Canada. This country-selection is not version specific; it applies to all versions. So I can't rely on the "release this version manually" option to control the date.

I don't want to make it unavailable in India and Canada because it's considered a bad thing (besides troubling people who might want to download again).

Does anyone know how I can stage the app for only a few countries, while keeping it live for other countries? The main purpose being ability to issue pre-launch promo codes that work for US/RoW (while keeping it live in Canada and India)